# White list с помощью iptables для прокси

Tags: список, iptables, прокси, whitelist

Всем добрый вечер! В общем задача такая: поднял сервер для прокси, который указываю в клиентских конфигах для подключения, задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать вайт лист на виртуальном сервере, и разрешить доступ только к указанным ip vpn серверов, чтобы пользователи не использовали прокси отдельно от vpn. Как это можно реализовать с помощью iptables? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что вам за месяц не ответил никто, т.к. это довольно просто.

---

Вариант 1:
Если белых айпи адресов не много, вы можете для каждого адреса прописать правила, которое будет разрешать доступ к порту:

```
# разрешить айпи адресам 91.121.75.131 и 91.121.75.132 доступ к порту 3306
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 91.121.75.131 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 91.121.75.132 -j ACCEPT

# остальные айпи адреса на порт 3306 запретить
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

---

Вариант 2:
Если белых айпи очень много, то лучше использовать ipset.

Установить ipset:

```
apt install ipset -y
```

Далее создаете в нем список и добавляете в него все свои белые айпи:

```
# создать список whitelist_ips
ipset create whitelist_ips iphash

# добавляем айпи в список
ipset add whitelist_ips 91.121.75.131
ipset add whitelist_ips 91.121.75.132
```

Теперь осталось разрешить подключения на порт айпи адресам из этого whitelist_ips списка:

```
# разрешить айпи адресам из списка whitelist_ips доступ к порту 3306
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m set --match-set whitelist_ips src -j ACCEPT

# остальные айпи адреса на порт 3306 запретить
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```